# collectionview inside tableview on expand collapse with dynamic cell height. objective c

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview

i need when i expand-collpase tableview indide tableviewcell i opened collectionview, also i need dynamic height of collectionview according to its item.also tableviewcell height dynamic. currently i am statically chaing height based on expand collpase.[I need similar to this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAx5d.png)

```
 - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
  if (self.selectedIndex == indexPath.row) {
     return 150;
  }else{
     return 40;
  }
}
```

tableview method for adjusting row height, i want it to be dynamically set height. also i have collectionview inside it. for reference i have 2 images it working fine but with static heigt i want it dynamically.[following is the image for reference][2]

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJ8Df.png
```

[image when collectionview item is more set, i want it to set dynamically](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAx5d.png)

Answer (score 0):

First,get the cell's model,then calculate with image count,for example:

`// cell height is 40
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return model.images.count / 6 * 40
}`